# Doctrine ODM Document with two Discriminator Fields

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it someway possible to have two discriminator fields in one document?
I have a collection Logs in Mongo. Each log has a category field and an action field. The combination of those fields forms the structure of the Log.

Example:
We have a category "element" and subcategories of "element" (the action field) "create", "file"

```
// Log element.create
{
     //common Log attributes
     category: 'element',
     action: 'create',

     //specific attributes for each Log type
     parent_element: ...
}

// Log element.file
{
     //common Log attributes
     category: 'element',
     action: 'file',

     //specific attributes for each Log type
     file_size: ...
     file_type: ...
}
```

Is there a workaround how to get from document manager instances of correct Classes by those two fields ?
I tried to create a Base Log Class that has the dicriminator field for the category attribute and an Element Class that extends Base Log class and it this class I set the dicriminator field for the action attribute. Then a Create Class that extends the Element. But this way it doesn't work 'cause doc. manager returns ony Element instances.

```
/**
 * @ODM\Document(collection="log")
 * @ODM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_COLLECTION")
 * @ODM\DiscriminatorField("category")
 * @ODM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "element"="Element"
 * })
 */
class Log {}  

/**
 * @ODM\Document
 * @ODM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_COLLECTION")
 * @ODM\DiscriminatorField("action")
 * @ODM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "create"="Create"
 * })
 */
class Element extends Log{} 

/**
 * @ODM\Document
 */
class Create extends Element{}
```